# Error when opening Google chrome from the terminal

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu

Chrome opens fine but I always get a message. Just installed chrome today.
Here's the message:

```
[23956:23956:0124/080528.875465:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(378)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[23911:23936:0124/080531.984723:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[23911:23936:0124/080531.984749:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay to loose all your chrome settings and data( Hope cloud sync is on), execute below command and try again

```sh
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
```

And launch again, it will solve the issue.

Verified in arch installation, but I believe this issue is generic.

Thanks.